# Regex to get the link in href from the tags other then <link> tag

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a paragraph of text in a javascript variable which contains multiple anchor, area and link tags. I would like to replace all of the href links other then the link tags with some other link. For example my current regex matching all the href not containing (mailto:) and (abc-url)

```
var r_domain = 'testlink.com';
var s = 'someencryptedstring';

var pattern = /href[\s]*=[\s]*('|")(?!mailto:)(?!#)((?:(?!\abc-url\b)[^('|")])*)('|")/ig;

var replace_pattern = 'href=\"http://'+r_domain+'/link.php?str='+s+'&mailin-url=$2"';

var body = '<a href="http://example.com" >abc</a> test data <a href="http://test.com/test.php?str=someencryptedstring&abc-url=http://cdf.com" > link </a> test last <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://csslink.com/forms.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />  area test <a href="http://example_1.com" > xyz </a>';

var re      = new RegExp(pattern);
var replaced  = body.replace(re , replace_pattern);
console.log(replaced);
```

It should replace the below links only:

```
href="http://example.com"
href="http://example_1.com"
```

It should not replace the below links:

```
href="http://test.com/test.php?str=someencryptedstring&abc-url=http://cdf.com"
href="http://csslink.com/forms.css"
```

The output should be as below (console.log(replaced);):

```
<a href="http://testlink.com/link.php?str=someencryptedstring&mailin-url=http://example.com" >abc</a> test data <a href="http://test.com/test.php?str=someencryptedstring&abc-url=http://cdf.com" > link </a> test last <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://csslink.com/forms.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />  area test <a href="http://testlink.com/link.php?str=someencryptedstring&mailin-url=http://example_1.com" > xyz </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the regex for the pattern and replace_pattern and kept the other script as it is. It is working fine for me.

The new regex for the pattern and replace_pattern are as below:

```
var pattern = /(<(a|area) [^>]*)href[\s]*=[\s]*('|")(?!mailto:)(?!#)((?:(?!\abc-url\b)[^('|")])*)('|")/ig;

var replace_pattern = '$1href=\"http://'+r_domain+'/link.php?str='+s+'&mailin-url=$4"';
```